# dotnet core slow on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: .net-core, mono, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Dotnet core runtime is slow to start on Raspberry Pi 2

Raspberry Pi 2 was set up using the Lite (Raspbian 10, Buster) tar file from Raspbian site.

I installed openssh, php7.1, dotnet runtime and mono.  I already have a RabbitMQ server running on a separate linux box.

I am using the Getting Started Example #1 (hello-world) send code found on the RabbitMQ site, https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

On my Raspberry Pi 2 I have installed the following

- PHP 7.1 for testing the PHP Send code on the CLI
- dotnet 2.2 core for testing the C# Send code (as Console App)
- mono for testing the C# Send code as Framework 4.7.2 (as Console App)

Added to the example tutorial code I added the Stopwatch so I could measure elapsed time.

The Results are below

- dotnet - Elapsed Time = 00:00:07.1991475
- mono   - Elapsed Time = 00:00:04.3602941
- php    - Elapsed Time = 00:00:00.1396138

I was under the impression that coding in Dotnet core would be faster than Framework (using mono).

So I thought it could be the RabbitMQ library (NuGet - RabbitMq.Client)

So decided to create two new projects with just the Hello World in the console.write.

The results were very similar.

- dotnet - 7 sec
- mono   - 4 sec
- php    - 0 sec

I was hoping to write my application in C# but unless I can get the performance issue resolved it looks like PHP is the way to go for my project.

Is there anything I can try to improve the performance?

After a lot of searching I have found similar problems but the articles were old and referred to dotnet core 2.1 in early releases.  I kinda hoped that by dotnet core 2.2 release the Arm CPU supported would have been better.  Especially with the push on IoT.

The Arm CPU I'm running in my Raspberry Pi 2 is ARMv7 rev 5 (v71).

I tried a Raspberry Pi 1, 2 & 3 and sadly the same results.
Except on a Raspberry Pi 1 you can't install dotnet (not supported on ARMv6 CPU) so only mono and PHP were tested on that.

Any ideas....

Comment: did you give the application any "warm up" time?  ie: how likely was it that everything was JIT'ed already?

Comment: Just a thought. Would it be possible to move the dotnet core runtime to a ram disk partition to improve the timings? If yes, which folders do you move and then symbolically link?

Answer (score 0):

To improve startup times there are a few things you can do according to the guidance and my experience.

1. If possible for your app migrate to dotnetcore3.0, which seems to have significant performance and startup benefits.
2. Enable TieredCompilation in your csproj. As described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#tiered-compilation

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <TieredCompilationQuickJit>true</TieredCompilationQuickJit>
>   <TieredCompilation>true</TieredCompilation>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

3. Use ReadyToRun images, by enabling this in your csproj. As described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#tiered-compilation
   In csproj.

[image]

Consider also using the Trimming feature to reduce binary sizes when publishing a single-exe. This reduces the amount of data needed to be read from disk to execute your app.

This issue has been discussed also in context of  [Amazon Lambda](https://medium.com/thundra/the-fundamental-problem-solving-net-lambda-cold-start-part-i-1ff4400bb6eb), that cold start times are quite high. 
[image]
So far it seems the best ways are reducing dll sizes, using ReadyToRun to reduce JIT times and TieredCompilation. These changes have worked for us remarkably, when combined with dotnetcore3.0.

There is some guidance provided by Scott Hanselman here https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx